# ImportError Python: Cannot Import Name Viewkeys

Tags: python, web, pycharm, anaconda, importerror

So I created this web scraper in python and I'm building it in Pycharm with Anaconda. My script was working, but somehow I think I messed something up in my computer and now I'm getting this error.

ImportError: cannot import name viewkeys

Also I can't seem to be able to install the module "mechanize" onto the anaconda directory.

Below is my code. If anyone can help resolve this that'd be great!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import numpy as np
#import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import urllib
import requests
import mechanize
import urlparse
import lxml
import sys
import re



def get_Sample_URL(Sample_Name):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.open("https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meteor/")

    "SELECTING THE FORM"
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    # Entering in the sample name
    br.form['sea'] = '%s' %Sample_Name
    br.submit()

    Link_List = list()
    for i in br.links():
        # Append the Base URL and the URL of the Sample
        new_url = urlparse.urljoin(i.base_url, i.url)
        # Insert URL's into a list
        Link_List.append(new_url)

    br.close()

    if len(Link_List)>9999999999:
       # print len(Link_List
        print ("Can't find data for: "), Sample_Name, "Perhaps try searching this one manually"
        #Manual_Search_File = np.loadtxt("/Users/edenmolina/Desktop/Metiorite_Manual_Search.txt", dtype='string', unpack=True
        Sample_URL = 0
        return Sample_URL
    #9 is the mumber of links for a sample that is not in the online database#
    elif len(Link_List)<=9:
        #print len(Link_List)
        #print ("No results found on database for: "), Sample_Name
        Sample_URL = 0
        return Sample_URL
    else:
        #print len(Link_List)
        #print len(Link_List), Sample_Name
        Sample_URL = Link_List[-4]
        return Sample_URL

"""Get the Classification"""
def get_Classification(URL):
    source = urllib.urlopen("%s"%URL).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

    Classification_List = []
    for k, td in enumerate(soup.find_all("td", {'class', 'inside'})):
        Classification = td.find_all("b")
        Classification_List.append(Classification)
    #print Classification_List[3]
    print (Classification_List[3][1].text)

"Define a fucntion that get the name, weathering, and shock stage of the sample"
def get_Name_Weathering_Shock(url):
    "Get the source code from the website"
    source = urllib.urlopen("%s" % url).read()

    # Convert the data to a Beautiful Soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

    """
    Print out the title of the webpage"""
    #print soup.title.string

    """"Getting the name"""
    Name_List = []
    for i, td in enumerate(soup.find_all("th", {'class', 'insidehead'})):
        Name = td.find_all("b")
        Name_List.append(Name)
    print ("Name Check: ", Name_List[0][0].text)

    # Get the data in the td subsections from the website
    data = soup.find_all('tr')

    # Getting the website data
    Website_Data = list()
    for tr in data:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        Website_Data.append(row)

    Weathering_Grade = [w for w in Website_Data if "Weathering grade:" in w]
    Shock_Stage = [s for s in Website_Data if "Shock stage:" in s]

    #Prints out the weathering and shock stage of the sample


    try:
        print (Weathering_Grade[1][1])
        np.savetxt("/Users/edenmolina/Desktop/Meteorite Data/%s.txt" % (Name[0][0].text), Weathering_Grade[1][1])
    except:
        print ("No Weathering")
    try:
        print (Shock_Stage[1][1])
    except:
        print ("No Shock Stage")

def get_Info(url, weatheringOrshock):
    "Get source code of website"
    source = urllib.urlopen("%s" % url).read()

    # Convert the data to a Beautiful Soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

    data = soup.find_all('tr')

    data = list()
    for tr in data:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        data.append(row)

    information = [w for w in data if "%s" %weatheringOrshock in w]

    try:
        print (information[1][1])
        return information[1][1]
    except:
        print ("No %s" %weatheringOrshock)



#get_SampleData("https://www.lpi.usra.edu/meteor/metbull.php?sea=NWA+001&sfor=names&ants=&falls=&valids=&stype=contains&lrec=50&map=ge&browse=&country=All&srt=name&categ=All&mblist=All&rect=&phot=&snew=0&pnt=Normal%20table&code=17011")

#AllData("NWA 002")


#LOAD THE SAMPLE NAMES FROM A TEXT FILE#
SampleNames_Text = np.loadtxt("/Users/edenmolina/Desktop/MetioriteNames.txt",delimiter="\n", dtype=np.str)
Number_of_Loops = len(SampleNames_Text)

"""FOR SAVING THE DATA"""


#Iterates through each of the samples in the text file and outputs the name, weathering, and the shock stage (if applicable)
for i in range(Number_of_Loops):
    print (SampleNames_Text[i])
    Sample_URL = get_Sample_URL("%s" % SampleNames_Text[i])

    if Sample_URL == 0 or len(Sample_URL) < 80.0:
        print ("")
    elif len(Sample_URL)<80.0:
        print ("Try Searching This Manually")

    else:
        Weathering = get_Info(Sample_URL, "Weathering grade:")
        Shock = get_Info(Sample_URL, "Shock stage:")
        Classification = get_Classification(Sample_URL)
    URL = get_Sample_URL("%s" %SampleNames_Text[i])
    print ("\n")
```

Stack Trace of the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/edenmolina/PycharmProjects/Meteorite/DataBase_Data_Extractor_V3.py", line 163, in <module>
    Sample_URL = get_Sample_URL("%s" % SampleNames_Text[i])
  File "/Users/edenmolina/PycharmProjects/Meteorite/DataBase_Data_Extractor_V3.py", line 34, in get_Sample_URL
    br.select_form(nr=0)
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 619, in select_form
    global_form = self._factory.global_form
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 260, in global_form
    self.forms()
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 267, in forms
    self._current_forms, self._current_global_form = self._get_forms()
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 282, in _get_forms
    if self.root is None:
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 247, in root
    response, verify=False))
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/mechanize/_html.py", line 145, in content_parser
    from html5lib import parse
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/html5lib/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "/Users/edenmolina/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six import with_metaclass, viewkeys, PY3
ImportError: cannot import name viewkeys
```

Comment: Please send a stack trace of your error. Also I suggest your read PEP8 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) python's coding standards so that your code looks more pythonic for python developers.

Comment: @MedhatGayed I updated the post with the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version control, then go back to your previous commits and see if you can get the application to work. This way you can isolate the change that caused the issue you're having.

One common reason for this type of error is circular imports in Python. I don't see it in the stack trace you pu but here. Google it anyway and see if that's what's happening here.

Another thing you can and should do is to have a virtual environment for your Python application. You can create one using the conda command. Once you have an environment, then install all the libraries you need for this application and try to run the app again.

I see `six` is being used by one of the libraries you're using. six is used to write code that's compatible with Python 2 and Python 3. So, maybe you changed your interpreter or environment and that's causing this error.

Let me know if you got the app working, I'd like to know what was causing the error. Thanks.